# Collapse with weights -- how to get the sample count, not the population count?

Tags: stata

I'm collapsing my data using weight, but I only want the weight to apply to my median and sum, not my count. I want my count to only be the sample size, not the population size.

Example:

```
. input outcome group weight

       outcome      group     weight
  1. 1 1 3
  2. 1 2 3
  3. 1 3 3
  4. end
```

Running `collapse (sum) outcome (count) n = outcome [pweight = weight], by(group)` gives

```
. list

     +---------------------+
     | group   outcome   n |
     |---------------------|
  1. |     1         3   3 |
  2. |     2         3   3 |
  3. |     3         3   3 |
     +---------------------+
```

Both the sum and count are using the weight. I want the count to be the sample size, i.e. 1 for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to have different weights when using `collapse`.

The few solutions I have in mind:

- create the weights yourself in the data, and compute your weighted statistics yourself
- have a look at the user-written version of collapse, which might include this feature. For instance, `collapse2` or `xcollapse`

Comment: In the end I just collapse once, save the dataset to a `tempfile`, then collapse again and merge with `tempfile`.